# TypeError: format is not a function in date-fns

Tags: javascript, node.js, date-fns

I am migrating from **moment** to **date-fns** and following docs on the official site.

I have installed date-fns from npm and when I try to use I get this error:

**TypeError: format is not a function**

I have tried import, require but they all give same error.

```
var format = require('date-fns/format')
import format from 'date-fns/format'
```

Also the **typeof(format)** returns **undefined**.

Using v1.29.0 on Nodejs

Comment: Same for startOfDay -> `import { startOfDay } from 'date-fns'`

Answer (score 14):

From the doc.

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';
```

Comment: For Node:

`const { format } = require("date-fns");`

Comment: Importing *date-fns* that way is bad for performance. Instead of importing only the function you would like to use, the entire module is loaded.
In date-fns@2.28.0 it loads 13.3 kB (68% of date-fns) of unnecessary data.

If you struggle to import date-fns with TypeScript check you have set in tsconfig.json: 
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

If you use Nx, ensure you set those options in the tsconfig.base.json or your application entry tsconfig (ex. packages/appName/tsconfig.json).

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to fix it by adding "esModuleInterop": true to tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same step as you did and it works fine for me.

**Most Important:** Upgrade your node version to v8.X or above.I am using node v10.8.0. You can follow [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu/) to upgrade version.

The library is available as an npm package, a Bower package, and is also distributed through a CDN.

You can use this properly by following give steps:

**Step 1:** First, you can install the package via running following command. (You might forget to install the package)

```
npm install date-fns --save

or

yarn add date-fns .
```

**Step 2:** It is used to get the formatted date string in the various formats and if you are using ES15 standards then you can import the package by adding following line above to your code.

```
import format from 'date-fns/format'
```

**Step 3:** Syntax for use will be as follow and list of various formats are given in the official doc. you can take reference from [here](https://date-fns.org/v1.28.0/docs/format)

```
format(date, [format='YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ', [options]])
```

**Step 4:** To take better understanding here is the simple example:

```
 var result = format(
      new Date(2014, 1, 11),
      'MM/DD/YYYY'
    ) 
console.log('Result: ',result);
```

Conclusion: I tried all the above steps and I got the following result in console:

```
Result:  02/11/2014
```

**Alternatively:** Try running follow code with REPL.
***Step 1:*** Open your terminal and run the command `sudo node`

**Step 2:**  Copy and paste below code in your terminal

```
var format = require('date-fns/format');
var result = format(
    new Date(2014, 1, 11),
    'MM/DD/YYYY'
) 
console.log('Result: ',result);
```

**Step 3:** Press enter and you will get `Result:  02/11/2014`  in your 
terminal console.

Comment: Could you please check node version. It must be v8.x or above.

Comment: Nodejs version 10

Comment: try running this code in your terminal with REPL.   var format = require('date-fns/format');

var result = format(
    new Date(2014, 1, 11),
    'MM/DD/YYYY'
  ) 

  console.log('Result: ',result);